# I'd like to know whether my attempt to increase duty cycle will work

Tags: oscillator, frequency, duty-cycle, multivibrator, astable

I've been looking for a solution to make an astable multivibrator give me a 90% duty cycle or a duty cycle above 50%. This is what I came up with. I have very limited resources and means of testing, so I'd like to ask for your opinions or what I should do to achieve my goal.

[image]

Comment: Any attempts of simulation? There's free software that would allow you to simulate it.

Comment: I apologise for what I'm about to say but why is it that people like me never get answers here, just more questions? Like I already stated that I have limited means of testing

Comment: I haven’t participated in your experience with this website so I can’t answer that. It would be useful for yourself to learn engineering tools because it’ll give you a very good head start to your career. I don’t think it makes a lot of sense to limit yourself to resources unless you’re specifically told by your instructor that simulation is not allowed. If that’s the case then you should tell us so that we know how to help you. The answer below has used a simulator. Why is that answer acceptable if you’re not able to use a simulator?

Comment: the schematic should be turned 90 degrees clockwise so that it meets schematic format convention ... power at top, ground at bottom, input at left, output at right  ... i think that the input/output direction could be reversed if you read/write right to left ........ drawing schematics to conention makes it easier to follow signal propagation through the circuit and easier to visualize voltage levels in the circuit

Comment: Well, I'm going to repeat what KingDuken says - get a simulator and simulate it. If you are at all interested in EE then that is the way forward. Just because you think that people like you never get answers here doesn't mean you should automatically write off what people are advising. Getting a simulator is one of the most important things you can ever do in EE. That's been regular good advice for at least 10 years. Get a simulator.

Comment: Delign it for 10% duty cycle and use the other output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easier if you don't stick to the original schematic.  One capacitor is ten times the other.
[image: astabil90]

Comment: Thank you for the succinct answer! You rock!

Comment: Your [version](https://imgur.com/a/R1pVj9Z) also works, but you still need to add two extra resistors.

Comment: Are you sure the 90% duty cycle square wave won't be at T1 as I've been running some tests and that's what I get!? (Based on the circuit simulation, answer)

Comment: Based on the [simulation](https://imgur.com/NWU0W2e), the rectangle on the T1 collector is quite distorted. This is caused by the charging current of the relatively high value capacitor C2.

Comment: Thank you for the response

Comment: I'm curious, if I wanted to change the duty cycle with resistance, which resistor would I replace with a potentiometer?